# What's the meaning of "working for himself" in this sentence "He’ll never get anywhere working for himself—he’s got no discipline."

Tags: interpretation

He’ll never get anywhere **working for himself**—he’s got no discipline.

for himself is alone(not working together with other people)?
for himself is for the benefit of himself like "selfish"(no benefit to others)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means he is his own boss. He does not go to work for someone else (i.e. a boss). As with most people who work for themselves, he will be doing work for a client who will pay him directly. If he worked for a boss, the client would pay his boss's company and he would be paid by the boss/company.